# Using a variable as part of a variable name

Tags: python

I have object1 which has many sub-objects in it.  These sub-objects are accessed in the form `object1.subobject`.  I have a function which returns a list of sub-objects of the original object.  All I would like to do is iterate through the list and access each sub-object.  Something like this:

```
temp_list = listSubChildren(object1)  #Get list of sub-objects
for sub_object in temp_list:          #Iterate through list of sub-objects
    blah = object1.sub-object         #This is where I need help 
    #Do something with blah           #So that I can access and use blah
```

I looked at similar questions where people used `dictionaries` and `getattr` but couldn't get either of those methods to work for this.

Comment: What is the type of the objects in `temp_list`?  Also, you probably need to change `sub-object` to `sub_object` as the former is a SyntaxError I think ...

Comment: You need to provide an example, as I would use `getattr` for this problem. I cannot see why this should not work...

Comment: So you would use `blah = object1.getattr(object1,sub_object)` ?

Comment: @BloonsTowerDefence -- nope.  `getattr` is a *builtin function*, not an *instance method* -- That one would be `__getattr__`, but don't call that directly here ...

Comment: What do you mean by 'sub-objects'? Do you mean instances of the object or a sub-class of the class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that if your `listSubChildren` method is returning strings as you imply, you can use the builtin [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function.

```
>>> class foo: pass
... 
>>> a = foo()
>>> a.bar = 1
>>> getattr(a,'bar')
1
>>> getattr(a,'baz',"Oops, foo doesn't have an attrbute baz")
"Oops, foo doesn't have an attrbute baz"
```

Or for your example:

```
for name in temp_list:
    blah = getattr(object1,name)
```

---

As perhaps a final note, depending on what you're actually *doing* with `blah`, you might also want to consider `operator.attrgetter`.  Consider the following script:

```
import timeit
import operator

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

def abc(f):
    return [getattr(f,x) for x in ('a','b','c')]

abc2 = operator.attrgetter('a','b','c')

f = foo()
print abc(f)
print abc2(f)

print timeit.timeit('abc(f)','from __main__ import abc,f')
print timeit.timeit('abc2(f)','from __main__ import abc2,f')
```

Both functions (`abc`, `abc2`) do nearly the same thing.  `abc` returns the list `[f.a, f.b, f.c]` whereas `abc2` returns a tuple much faster,  Here are my results -- the first 2 lines show the output of `abc` and `abc2` respectively and the 3rd and 4th lines show how long the operations take:

```
[1, 2, 3]
(1, 2, 3)
0.781795024872
0.247200965881
```

Note that in your example, you could use `getter = operator.attrgetter(*temp_list)`

Comment: The thing is that I need `blah` to equal `object1.name` ... so I would have `object1.firs`t, `object1.second`, `object1.third` ...

Comment: Which brings us back to my original question.  What does `listSubChildren` actually return?  If it returns an iterable like `["first","second","third"]` then this will set `blah` to `object1.first` on the first pass, then `object1.second`, then `object1.third` ...

Comment: Yes it returns strings.  Sorry for the confusion, this works indeed.

Comment: @BloonsTowerDefence -- I don't know what you plan on doing with `listSubChildren`, but you might want to also consider `operator.attrgetter`.  It's pretty neat.

Comment: *debates internally* ... Should I post about `f.__dict__[x]` too?  It's faster than `getattr`, but a lot uglier and not all classes have `__dict__` ...

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
temp_list = [] 
for property_name in needed_property_names:
    temp_list.append(getattr(object1, property_name))
```

So, getattr is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the class that `object1` is an instance of:

```
def getSubObjectAttributes(self):
    childAttrNames = "first second third".split()
    return [getattr(self, attrname, None) for attrname in childAttrNames]
```